# Ruby - Adding on to a Multidimensional Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array

I would like to loop through a process and add an object to my Database each time, but if it is not added properly I would like to collect the errors in a multidimensional array.  One array would keep which Lot it was that had the error and the second array will have the error message.

Here is my declaration:

```
errors = [[],[]]
```

So I would like the array to be formatted like this:

```
[[lot_count, "#{attribute}: #{error_message}" ]]
```

Which should look like this after looping:

```
[[1, "Name: Can not be blank" ],[1, "Description: Can not be blank" ],[2, "Name: Can not be blank" ]]
```

My problem is that it wont add it to the array. I'm not sure if the syntax is different for a multidimensional array.

This gives me nothing in my array

```
errors.push([[lot_count, "#{attribute}: #{error_message}" ]])
```

This also gives me nothing in my array

```
errors += [[lot_count, "#{attribute}: #{error_message}" ]]
```

Comment: Since you seems to always have the same sort of information in the inner array you might be better of using an array of [structs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html), e.g. an array of `Struct.new("DBError", :count, :attribute, :message)`. Then you can create structs and push them with `error << Struct::DBError.new(1, 'Name', 'Can not be blank')`.

Comment: Just an observation, but a Hash map would probably be more memory efficient way of doing this. Similar to Rails's ActiveModel::Errors [http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html]. Or maybe a Set [http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html] as you'll get a lot of the memory benefits of a Hash and some array functionality too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you nest your arrays too deep when pushing:

```
errors.push([lot_count, "Foo:Bar"])
# => [[], [], [1, "Foo:Bar"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could start with an empty array...

```
errors = []
```

...then build the single error array...

```
e = [lot_count, "#{attribute}: #{error_message}" ]
```

... and push it to the end of the errors array.

```
errors << e
# or errors.push(e)
```

This will give you your end result

```
[[1, "Name: Can not be blank" ],[1, "Description: Can not be blank" ],[2, "Name: Can not be blank" ]]
```

Comment: I was mistaken on how to declare a multidimensional array thanks!